# Django save signup form sent via Ajax with fetch() API

Tags: django

I am trying to send a signup form using Ajax and the fetch() API. The Ajax call works and I am able to send data to Django's backend:

Signup form registration/user-signup.html (this is loaded with Ajax into a modal window):

```
<h2>Sign up by filling in the form:</h2>
<form method="POST" id="signup-form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for field in form %}
    <p>
      {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
      {{ field }}
      {% if field.help_text %}
        <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
      {% endif %}
      {% for error in field.errors %}
        <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
    </p>
  {% endfor %}
  <button type="submit" id="signup-submit">Sign up</button>
</form>

<p>Do you already have an account? <a href="#">Log in</a> instead!</p>
```

Ajax call:

```
const sendForm = function(endpoint, formData) {
    const request = fetch(endpoint, {
        method: 'post',
        body: formData,
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        // pass CSRF token to the backend
        headers: {
            "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }
        
    }).then(console.log(formData))
}

const getForm = function(endpoint) { 
    const request = fetch(endpoint)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => modal.innerHTML = data) 
        .then(() => {
            const signupForm = document.getElementById('signup-form')
            // prevent default submit behaviour
            signupForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault()
                    // store form data to send to the backend
                    const formData = new FormData(signupForm)
                 
                    sendForm(endpoint, formData)
                    
                })
            }
        )
}

btnSignup.addEventListener('click', function(){getForm('/accounts/signup')})
```

If I check the request I get on the backend, I can see that form data is passed correctly and I can access it from the server:

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import SignUpView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('signup', SignUpView, name="signup"),
]
```

views.py

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
        for value in request.POST.values():
            print(value)
```

Output:

```
giulio
giulio@g.com
Password123
Password123
```

So data is correctly sent to the server. Now, if I try to instantiate the signup form to later save it, it does not work. This is what I'm doing:

views.py

```
def SignUpView(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for value in request.POST.values():
            print(value)
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST) 
        
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            
            form.save()
            
            print("Success!")
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return redirect('dashboard')
        else:
            print("Failure!")
            return HttpResponse("error")

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()

        return render(request, 'registration/user-signup.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# We need set User equal to our custom user model 
User = get_user_model()

# We need to extend Django's built in UserCreationForm if we want to use extra fields like email
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', )
```

It looks like I'm stuck at `form = SignUpForm(request.POST)`, I don't really understand why I'm not able to pass the data to the form instance and later save it.

Do you have any hint on how to save this form?

Comment: Please share your sign up form html template

Comment: Hi @datosula, my bad. I've added the HTML form in the question text! Thanks

Comment: Are you using the same form in the modal (SignUpForm) as you are when trying to POST?

Comment: Yes, I'm rendering the form with the getForm function which does a fetch() API call to endpoint "/accounts/signup" which is bound to my SignUpView. The SignUpView when it receives a GET request it sends the form which gets rendered.

Comment: What does it mean "form does not work"? Does it have validation problems, or you save form but model is not created? Does it raise any exception?